# Infinite while loop reset when a function is run

Tags: python

I was just wondering if I could remove some redundancy for a help function in a text-game. What I have right now is at the start of every function hint = 0, and hint is increased one every time an invalid answer is entered.

Here is what I have at the moment (inside every function):

```
hint = 0
    valid = False
    while valid == False:

        print "Would you like to begin?"

        begin = raw_input("> ")

        if "yes" in begin:
            valid = True
            print "Great!\n"
            start.start()
        elif "no" in begin:
            quit.quit()
        else:
            error.error(1)
            hint += 1

        if hint > 4:
            print "\nYou may choose from \"yes\" and \"no\"."
```

Comment: Why do you have `start.start()` and `quit.quit()`?

Comment: In different files. It's a project for a tutorial, I'm just practicing using `import`.

Comment: Which parts of the above are you considering the redundant part that you are wanting to factor out?

Comment: the `hint = 0`, `hint += 1` and the `if hint > 4:` block. Maybe not all of them, just as many as I can.

Comment: Could you edit to provide at least the function declaration?  Hint must be defined outside the function?

Comment: I'm leaning towards that this should be some sort of REPL with a object(s) that can handle the the input and if they fail the REPL will keep count and will print the valid inputs from the object(s) when the last successful attempt was more than four attempts ago.  But that may be a heavier design than you are looking for, may be a bit bigger than the what you are asking, and my or not the design you are pursuing.  A function with the counter captured in a closure likely would work to just factor out those bits.  I think the code savings would be small but it would factor out the > 4  logic.

Comment: `while not valid:` is nicer than `while valid == False:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code use decorator to separate hint logic and command logic. Every command is handled by a function which can be decorated by Hint object.

When the function return False, the count in Hint object will increase and when it's larger than the limit, it will print out a hint message.

When the function return a tuple it will be called by the main loop.

```
class Hint(object):
    def __init__(self, n, msg):
        self.n = n
        self.msg = msg

    def __call__(self, f):
        def wrap(*args, **kw):
            count = 1
            while True:
                ret = f(*args, **kw)
                if ret == False:
                    count += 1
                    if count > self.n:
                        print self.msg
                        count = 0
                else:
                    break
            return ret
        return wrap

def start_at(place):
    print "start at %d" % place
    return "start"

@Hint(3, "You may choose from 1, 2, 3.")
def start():
    print "What place will you start?"
    cmd = raw_input("> ")
    try:
        place = int(cmd)
        if place not in (1,2,3):
            return False
        else:
            return start_at, (place,)
    except ValueError:
        return False

def quit():
    print "I will quit"
    return "quit"

@Hint(4, "You may choose from yes and no.")
def begin():
    print "Would you like to begin?"
    cmd = raw_input("> ")
    if "yes" in cmd:
        print "Great!\n"
        return start, ()
    elif "no" in cmd:
        print "Bad!\n"
        return quit, ()
    else:
        return False

call_func, args = begin, ()
while True:        
    ret = call_func(*args)
    if isinstance(ret, tuple):
        call_func, args = ret
    else:
        break
```

Here is some test:

```
Would you like to begin?
> abc
Would you like to begin?
> def
Would you like to begin?
> 123
Would you like to begin?
> 345
You may choose from yes and no.
Would you like to begin?
> yes
Great!

What place will you start?
> 5
What place will you start?
> fg
What place will you start?
> sd
You may choose from 1, 2, 3.
What place will you start?
> 2
start at 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import count
for hint in count()
    print "Would you like to begin?"

    begin = raw_input("> ")

    if "yes" in begin:
        print "Great!\n"
        start.start()
        break

    elif "no" in begin:
        quit.quit()
    else:
        error.error(1)

    if hint > 4:
        print "\nYou may choose from \"yes\" and \"no\"."
```

Now the next problem is what does `start.start()` do? It looks/feels like you might be using function calls like a GOTO

Comment: I'm using the modules like functions just for practice with `import` (this is for a tutorial). that actually looks like exactly what I wanted, thanks!